# Iterate through Google Sheets - how to create a loop?

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I'm a newbie in programming. I'm trying to achieve similar effect in Google Sheets that I've achieved with .xls file (with openpyxl library). This is just a part of simple reminder-bot that posts a reminder (to Slack channel) seven days before the date found in .xls or Sheets.

My code sample with Excel example:

```
def excel_check():
zakres = datetime.timedelta(days = 7)
dzisiaj = (datetime.date.today() + zakres)
miesiac = dzisiaj.month
rok = dzisiaj.year
dzien = dzisiaj.day
data_check = datetime.datetime(rok, miesiac, dzien, 0, 0, 0)

wb = load_workbook(filename = "daty.xlsx", data_only = True)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name("sheet1")

cell_range = ws["B2":"B25"]
for row in cell_range:
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == data_check:
                imie = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=1).value
                dzial = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=3).value
                typ_umowy = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=4).value
                przelozony = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=5).value
AND HERE WE'RE PERFORMING SLACK/API MESSAGE WITH STRINGS ABOVE (imie, dzial, typ_umowy)
```

I've managed to change the code into gspread action:

```
def excel_check():
zakres = datetime.timedelta(days = 7)
dzisiaj = (datetime.date.today() + zakres)
miesiac = dzisiaj.month
rok = dzisiaj.year
dzien = dzisiaj.day
data_check = datetime.datetime(rok, miesiac, dzien, 0, 0, 0)

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"]
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("validcredentialsitworks", scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open_by_url("myurl").sheet1

cell_range = wks.range("B2:B25")
for row in cell_range:
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == data_check:
                imie = wks.cell(row=cell.row, column=1).value
                dzial = wks.cell(row=cell.row, column=3).value
                typ_umowy = wks.cell(row=cell.row, column=4).value
AND HERE WE'RE PERFORMING SLACK/API MESSAGE WITH STRINGS ABOVE (imie, dzial, typ_umowy)
```

But unfortunately it doesn't act like the Excel part above (Excel part sends the proper message to Slack, gspread part doesn't). I've got an error message:

```
TypeError: 'Cell' object is not iterable
```

It's probably something wrong with the syntax, but I can't find out what.

Could you please give me a hint?

In short, what's the equivalent of:

```
for row in cell_range:
    for cell in row:
        print cell.value
```

in gspread?

Comment: Your question was answered, but I suggest to please name your variables a little bit better, and if not please comment the code what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the google sheets API to pass your data to the above script. I followed [these simple steps](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) to easily get my data. Once you have that the rest of the code should remain the same.

[This is a link to my post](https://tadatmyasthoughts.wordpress.com/2017/02/06/using-instantmusic-to-auto-download-shared-playlist-on-google-sheets/) where I parsed the data in my spreadsheet. If you need help you can refer to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please look at the edited question (i've added some code). I'm able to connect to my Gspreadsheet, but the rest of code doesn't perform like in the Excel part. There's an error message: TypeError: 'Cell' object is not iterable.

Comment: Please read through [this](https://github.com/burnash/gspread). Print your cell_range and see what the elements of your list are and iterate accordingly. I have not used Gspread personally.

Answer (score 0):

> It's probably something wrong with the syntax, but I can't find out
>   what :(

From the [gspread docs](http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=worksheet#gspread.Worksheet.range), range method returns a list of cells, not a list of rows. That's why there is a mistake you've mentioned: you cannot iterate through `row`, which is actually a cell.

If you're not writing to a spreadsheet, only reading from it - I may recommend loading it to csv first:

```
with open('wks.csv', 'wb') as out:
    out.write(wks.export(format='csv'))
```

and then iterate through a csv file:

```
import unicodecsv

with open('wks.csv', "rb") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = unicodecsv.reader(csv_file, encoding='utf-8', delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was the following:

```
for r in range(1,sheet.row_count - 1):
    row = sheet.row_values(r)
```

This will print out a list for each row in the sheet. So you can add code after:

```
    if row[0] == 'January':
        sheet.delete_row(r)
```

I realize It's not a complete answer to your question, but maybe it's enough to get started.